# Htacces rewriterule not working with two joker characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)data(.*)$ http://regi.krater.hu/$1data$2 [R=301,L]
```

It should make http://krater.hu/xxxxdataxxxx.php -> http://regi.krater.hu/xxxxdataxxxxx.php
I still don't understand where is my error? Thak you for the help! :)

Full code:
    # BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)data(.*)$ http://regi.krater.hu/$1data$2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: *"joker characters"*? Like Jack Nicholson and Heath Ledger? ;)  What's not working?  What are you seeing vs. what you're expecting to see?

Comment: It's not redirecting. Joker like wild cards. I want to redirect the  first url to the second, only when it contains the word "data".

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` turned on? Have you tried turning on the rewrite log?

Comment: Not for me :( 

http://krater.hu/krater.php?do=5&action=a&data[0]=637&kkulcs=fekete%20g

my htaccess file: 
http://pastebin.com/M5iHneJV

Comment: yes it's turned on, as the index.php rewrite rule works. I don't know how can i see the rewrite log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example it appears that you are entering `data` in QUERY_STRING not in `URI`. Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)data(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://regi.krater.hu/%1data%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Wow it works! So this was the problem. if the url contains ?do... then it's a query string and i have to use this format, I see now.
Thank you very much!